# Restoring Printer Settings

Tags: windows, configuration, printing, settings

We're trying to standardise our printing environment to provide consistent settings across our various print queues. To do this, we would like create a settings file per model of printer so that they can be used to quickly deploy new Windows print servers and queues with standard settings.
We've used

```
Rundll32.exe PrintUI.dll,PrintUIEntry /Ss /n <Queue> /a <SettingsFile>
```

to create the settings files without error. However, now that I am trying to use them to restore the settings on another server with

```
Rundll32.exe PrintUI.dll,PrintUIEntry /Sr /n <Queue> /a <SettingsFile>
```

I'm getting the error "Operation could not be completed (error 0x0000000c)." This translates to the Windows error code: ERROR_INVALID_ACCESS, though that might be a red-herring.

Both the servers I'm using are Windows Server 2008 R2 RTM and my queues are both pointing at the same printer with the same driver installed. UAC is disabled on both machines and I am running as an Adminsitrator.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how to troubleshoot this issue? Alternatively, what methods could we use to provide consistent print queue settings at a per-device level for 100s of print queues?

Many thanks.

Comment: Just encountered this myself using rundll32 printui.dll /Sr /n "printer name" /a "settings.dat" after running the same command with the /Ss switch, under Windows 7 64bit Enterprise. Gives the same error as above.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently the rundll32.exe executable calls the 32-bit version of Tcpmonui.dll from the wrong location (probably due to wow64 filesystem redirection).

There's a hotfix available for Win7 64-bit and Windows 2008 R2 over at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/981070

Comment: Thanks, the hotfix solves the problem. However since its a 32/64bit issue, I've now tried using the 64bit version of rundll32.exe in SysWOW64, which I've found works as expected on systems without the hotfix applied: `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Rundll32.exe PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /Sr /n "printer name" /a "settings.dat"`.

Comment: Odd that this 32bit/64bit issue only seems to arise for the /Sr switch, since I hadn't come across it with any of the other uses of PrintUI.dll such as installing printers.

Comment: @gsreynolds the one in SysWOW64 IS the 32-bit version

Comment: So it is, thanks. Not exactly the obvious acronym at first glance ever... WOW64 = "Windows 32-bit on Windows 64-bit"... Not had much exposure to this aspect of Windows, thanks for the correction.